# How can I render a list select box (dropdown) with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there anything out of the box that bootstrap supports to render a "regular" defacto drop down list select box?  That is, where the drop down box is a list of values and if selected populate the contents of the list box?

Something similar to this functionality?

http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/select/

[image]

Comment: Do you mean - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls (under **Selects**) ?

Comment: This is how normal selects work. Its a list of options, you select one, and that become the value. How is what you are asking different?

Comment: Now I'm just wondering how I can replace that contrived looking dropdown icon with a nice looking caret.  :)

Comment: `-prefix-appearance: none` then use background image ?

Comment: From getbootstrap.com: Avoid using <select> elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers.

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with the idea of disregarding a native control for the sake of a visual framework. I'm genuinely surprised that bootstrap doesn't have a better solution using `<select>`. while bootstrap utilises `<ul>` for drop downs, that is ultimately a misleading use of said tag.  given all the JQuery pomp in bootstrap, i wonder why they didn't alter the caret for select themselves.  That would seem a far more graceful solution than misappropriating `ul`.

Answer (score 424, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 uses the `.form-control` class to style form components.

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
</select>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls

Comment: Found myself here because I needed a Bootstrap look for Elm without using `bootstrap.js`. The key visual difference between this and the 'full' bootstrap solution (alluded to by @JonathanEdwards) is that the menu which appears is boxy, less pretty, like the `alert` box your browser provides. Small issue really. The un-clicked selector looks exactly like a Bootstrap one, however.

Answer (score 39):

You can make a bootstrap select using the Dropdown component...

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="selectA">Select<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item I</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item II</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item III</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item IV</a></li>
</ul>


let links = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item')
links.forEach(element => element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let text = element.innerText
    document.getElementById('selectA').innerText = text
}))
```

[Bootstrap 5](https://codeply.com/p/WHZEBa14No)

**Original answer (Bootstrap 3)**

Another option is to make the Bootstrap dropdown behave like a select using jQuery...

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

[Bootstrap 3](https://codeply.com/p/3cF6zAEc1l)

Comment: Useful when you don't want a form. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/brynner/hkwhaqsj/6/

HTML

```
<div class="input-group-btn select" id="select1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="selected">One</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu option" role="menu">
        <li id="1"><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li id="2"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('body').on('click','.option li',function(){
    var i = $(this).parents('.select').attr('id');
    var v = $(this).children().text();
    var o = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+i+' .selected').attr('id',o);
    $('#'+i+' .selected').text(v);
});
```

CSS

```
.select button {width:100%; text-align:left;}
.select .caret {position:absolute; right:10px; margin-top:10px;}
.select:last-child>.btn {border-top-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px;}
.selected {padding-right:10px;}
.option {width:100%;}
```

Comment: Use 'min-width' in '.select button' class according to what you need.

Answer (score 12):

Another option could be using [bootstrap select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/). On their own words:

> A custom select / multiselect for Bootstrap using button dropdown, designed to behave like regular Bootstrap selects.

Comment: Does exactly what it says, and is available via cdn.

Answer (score 11):

Skelly's nice and easy answer is now outdated with the changes to the dropdown syntax in Bootstap. Instead use this:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.form-group').find('button[data-toggle="dropdown"]').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way without using the .form-control is this:

```
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
        $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
        $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
      });
```

```js
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="btn-group">
  <button  type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Test <span class="caret"> </span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href='#'>test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>test 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ben's code requires the parent div to have the form-group class (I was using btn-group), this is a slightly different version which just searches for the closest div and may even be a bit faster.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $(this).closest('div').find('button[data-toggle="dropdown"]').html(selText + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap3 `.form-control` is cool but for those who love or need the drop-down with button and ul option, here is the updated code. I have edited the code by Steve to fix jumping to the hash link and closing the drop-down after selection.

Thanks to Steve, Ben and Skelly!

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $(this).closest('div').find('button[data-toggle="dropdown"]').html(selText + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').removeClass("open");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently fighting with dropdowns and I'd like to share my experiences:

There are specific situations where `<select>` can't be used and must be 'emulated' with dropdown.

For example if you want to create  bootstrap input groups, like Buttons with dropdowns (see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns). Unfortunately `<select>` is not supported in input groups, it will not be rendered properly.

Or does anybody solved this already?
I would be very interested on the solution.

And to make it even more complicated, you can't use so simply `$(this).text()` to catch what user selected in dropdown if you're using glypicons or font awesome icons as content for dropdown. For example: 
     `<li id="someId"><a href="#0"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a></li>`
Because in this case there is no text and if you will add some then it will be also displayed in dropdown element and this is unwanted.

I found two possible solutions:

1) 
Use `$(this).html()` to get content of the selected `<li>` element and then to examine it, but you will get something like `<a href="#0"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>` so you need to play with this to extract what you need.

2)
Use `$(this).text()` and hide the text in element in hidden span:
     `<li id="someId"><a href="#0"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hidden">text</span></i></a></li>`.
For me this is simple and elegant solution, you can put any text you need, text will be hidden, and you don't need to do any transformations of  `$(this).html()` result like in option 1) to get what you need.

I hope it's clear and can help somebody :-)