# get selected choice in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have this inside a form:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

when it submits how I get the value of the selected choice in php?I have the other fields but I don't know how to get this one.Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is useful to you: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150954/how-can-i-render-a-list-select-box-dropdown-with-bootstrap

Comment: But i think that what you really need is in @cmcculloh answer right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437446/how-to-display-selected-item-in-bootstrap-button-dropdown-title

Comment: that's what I need! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A drop down list in a `<form>` tag uses the `<select>` tag along with a set of `<option>` tags each with a different `value` parameter. Your form will also need an `<input type="submit">`. The following is an example of a properly constructed drop down list form.

```
<form>
  <select name="lang">
    <option value="html">html</option>
    <option value="css">CSS</option>
    <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This will break the bootstrap styling the OP had in his question.

Comment: It is intended as an example of how to create a form. Not gonna do it all for him ;)

Comment: like I said, that's inside a form

Comment: Placing it inside a form is not sufficient to create the form. You need to use the `<select>` tag to communicate with the `<form>` ie pass the current selected `value` to your form's handler.