# Desire To Move Bootstrap Pulldown to left of buttons. PHP Web page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I had a pretty simple PHP pulldown that sat/sits where it should: to the left of some buttons. I have been "modernizing" this webpage with BootStrap, found how to use it for a pulldown [on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150954/how-can-i-render-a-list-select-box-dropdown-with-bootstrap).

Here is where it currently sits without Bootstrap: (word to the right is what was picked from the pulldown, in this case Sort by "Type").

[image: Before bootstrap added]

However when I add bootstrap class (class=\"form-control\"), it puts it above the buttons rather than in front of them. Does anyone have any ideas to keep it in the previous location but take advantage of the good look Bootstrap provides?

[image: Screenprint of pulldown's current location]

My PHP Code before changing class to Bootstrap class:

```
echo "<select name=\"cboSortBy\" class=\"admin\"  onChange=\"submitForm('Available.php');\" style=\"width:100px;height:20px;\">";
echo "<option></option>";
echo "<option value=\"Date\">Sort By Date</option>";
echo "<option value=\"Trip Name\">Trip Name</option>";
echo "<option value=\"Leader Name\">Leader Name</option>";
echo "<option value=\"Type\">Type</option>";
echo "<option value=\"Level\">Level</option>";
echo "<option value=\"Only Mine\">Only Mine</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

Here is the HTML output:

```
<br><select name="cboSortBy" class="form-control" onchange="submitForm('Available.php');" style="width:100px;height:20px;"><option></option>
<option value="Date">Sort By Date</option>
<option value="Trip Name">Trip Name</option>
<option value="Leader Name">Leader Name</option><option value="Type">Type</option>
<option value="Level">Level</option>
<option value="Only Mine">Only Mine</option>
</select>
<span class="tiny1">(Date)</span>
<span class="tiny1">&nbsp;&nbsp;::&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="color:white;" onclick="popitup(0,'Add.php',1,0,0);"><span class="tiny1" onmouseover="this.style.borderBottom='0.05cm dashed Tomato'" onmouseout="this.style.borderBottom='Transparent'" style="border-bottom-color: transparent;">Add Custom</span></a>
<span class="tiny1">&nbsp;&nbsp;::&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="switchboard.php" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" style="color:white;"><span class="tiny1" onmouseover="this.style.borderBottom='0.05cm dashed Tomato'" onmouseout="this.style.borderBottom='Transparent'">Switchboard</span></a>
<span class="tiny1">&nbsp;&nbsp;::&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<a href="destroysession.php" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" style="color:white;"><span class="tiny1" onmouseover="this.style.borderBottom='0.05cm dashed Tomato'" onmouseout="this.style.borderBottom='Transparent'">Log Off</span></a>
<span class="tiny1">&nbsp;&nbsp;::&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="tiny1">Inflate</span><input type="checkbox" name="chkVerbose" class="tinycheckbox" onclick="submitForm('Available.php');">
<br>
<hr class="fatblue">
```

Comment: While screenshots are helpful, it's not quite enough to troubleshoot without the code.

Comment: Yes Jeff, sorry. I turned off the computer, realized my omission, turned it back on,  and put in the code for the pulldown. Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a jsfiddle of your code... looks like the issue has more to do with the HTML/CSS part of your page than the PHP part...

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHP. Post your HTML as a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. Necessity required that I figure something out. Now I know this is not really a "responsive web" solution, but I don't need that at this time. If so, I would have used a grid with row yada yada.

I searched bootstrap.css for the "form_control" class that formatted the pulldown like I wanted and copied it into a style tag on the webpage and renamed it (for now, at least). Then if you notice, I disabled the "display: block;" and "padding: 6px 12px". This lined things up pretty good. For now. Any advice beyond this is welcome also.

```
<style>
.form-control_single {
  /*display: block;*/

  width: 100px;
  height: 26px;

  /*padding: 6px 12px;*/
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
       -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.form-control_single:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
}

</style>
```